# Why is keyword sched used before down function of the semaphore code?

Tags: linux-kernel

```
   `static noinline void __sched __down(struct semaphore *sem)`
```

In the above function, why is `__sched` used before the `__down` function of the semaphore code?

Comment: that `sched` is short form of `scheduler`. If you see, `__sched __down` calls another method `__sched __down_common` passing `MAX_SCHEDULE_TIMEOUT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__sched` is a macro and not keyword, adding an attribute to the function, think of it as some added meta-information.

As defined in `<linux/sched.h>`:

```
/* Attach to any functions which should be ignored in wchan output. */
#define __sched         __attribute__((__section__(".sched.text")))
```

So adding the `__sched` macro to a function results in supressing the wchan information for that function.

Comment: so, will it matter if i dont use it in my function?